# Wait for ImageOpened event handler in C#

Tags: windows, winforms, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have an image that I need to get from the web, but I need to wait for the image to be downloaded before doing anything else. 
So this is my code

```
BitmapImage bm = new BitmapImage(new Uri(imageUri));
bm.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.None;
bm.ImageOpened += (sd, args) => {
    Debug.WriteLine("loaded");
    mre.Set();

};
mre.WaitOne();
Debug.WriteLine(imageUri);
```

The problem is the code inside `ImageOpened` event handler never runs. So my program just stops
Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You can't ignore the ImageFailed event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use WebClient to download web images. Here's an async method:

```
    private Task<BitmapImage> downloadImage(string imageUri)
    {
      TaskCompletionSource<BitmapImage> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<BitmapImage>();
      IsolatedStorageFile isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

      WebClient wc = new WebClient();
      wc.OpenReadCompleted += (s, e) =>
      {
          if (e.Error == null && !e.Cancelled)
          {
              BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
              bmp.SetSource(e.Result);

              tcs.SetResult(bmp);
          }
            else { tcs.SetResult(null); }
      };
      wc.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(imageUri, UriKind.Absolute));

      return tcs.Task;
  }
```

Here's how to use it:

```
BitmapImage img = await downloadImage("web url goes here");
if (img == null) 
{
    //Error handling goes here
}
```